# Renew test accounts?

Tags: google-classroom

I was setup 30 days with test accounts and need to continue/renew access to those accounts for testing.  How do I request updates to the existing test accounts?  I sent a request for a new account setup for testing but if we have a lot of data/courses, etc in our existing test accounts, how can we renew our access to that account every 30 days?  Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 1):

Well, based on the [Google Classroom API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/access#get_classroom_test_accounts), it is noted here that Test accounts will expire after 30 days and do not allow users to access Google apps other than Classroom. So I think there is no way to renew it. Your only option is the one that you already did by making or requesting a new test account.

Comment: Yep, so far, I agree.  That's what I did and will continue to since I have found no way to renew a GC sandbox.  Thanks

Comment: Are you able to request a new test account every thirty days?  How long do the requests take?

Comment: Neal, sorry for delay, typically just a day or two, pretty quick turn-around.